Accessing a key's value in a sub array and using that to order the items in an object
I've got a working component which receives a list of employees from an API and displays them on a page. I want to add an additional functionality where the administrator will be able to choose the order in which the employees are displayed. ("Display order" in the API response) Therefore, I need to access the value of this before doing anything. Then,I need to reorder the employees so that the employees with a "Display order" value are placed before the other employees who have a null value.
I'm just a hobbyist and this is proving quite difficult. I'm basically getting nowhere with this. I've read about how to sort and so on, but it seems that adding to this code I have isn't working. How should I go about making additional modifications to my this.employees object?
Example of API response:
{
  id: 200779, 
  first_name: "Sample", 
  last_name: "Name", 
  include_as_teacher: "1",
  subjects: "Math, Science",
  status: "Active",
  custom_fields: [
    {
      field_id: 17363, 
      name: "Custom field 1", 
      value: "something"
    }
    {
      field_id: 17940, 
      name: "Custom field 2", value: 
      "something"
      }
    {
      field_id: 18262, 
      name: "Display order", 
      value: "1"
    }
  ]
}

My vue code:
  mounted() {

    fetch("api url", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .then(response => response.filter((e) => e.include_as_teacher = 1 && e.subjects != null && e.status == "Active"))
      .then(
        (response) =>
          (this.employees = this.cloneEmployees = response.map((e) => ({
            id: e.id,
            first_name: e.first_name,
            last_name: e.last_name,
            subjects: e.subjects.split(","),
            // order: e.custom_fields???.value
          }))))
          .then((response) => this.subjects = [...new Set(this.cloneEmployees.flatMap(item => item.subjects))].sort())
         
    },


You need to provide a comparison function to the sort() method. It can get the nested elements and compare them.

I hope you understand that this.employees and this.cloneEmployees will both be the same array, not clones of each other.

Your API response is a single object, not an array that can be filtered, mapped, or sorted.

Your third .then() won't work, because console.log() doesn't return the object that it logs. And filter() isn't asynchronous, there's no need for another .then() after it.

What you want is .then(response => { console.log(response); response = response.filter(...).map(...).sort(...); ... })
